# Given a login name (windows or SQL Server) how can I determine the database user name for a given login using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, authentication

If I have a SQL Server login name (windows or SQL Server) how can I determine the database user name for a given login using TSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the db context:

```
select L.name [Login], U.name [User] from 
    sys.server_principals L
inner join 
    sys.database_principals U
on 
    L.sid = U.sid
WHERE
    L.name = 'LittleBobbyTables'
```

Comment: The sid is the connector between the tables - thanks. It works fine.